# How to reuse django-model in elasticsearch and neo4j?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-models, neo4j

I am developing a `django` application in `python`. It consists several models. It makes uses of `MySQL` relation database. For certain features, it also makes use of `elasticsearch` and `neo4J` graph database. I am using `elasticsearch_dsl` library for `elasticsearch` and `neomodel` library for dealing with `neo4j`.

For certain models, when new object is created, it's entered into `elasticsearch` and `neo4j`, along with `MySQL`. I am required to `redefine` same model(which i defined for `django-orm`)for `elasticsearch_dsl` and `neomodel` also. As a result, in my project, there're three different types of definition of same model.

Is there any DRY way to do this ? I mean, I want to define model for `django-orm` and then `elasticsearch_dsl` and `neomodel` library automatically creates their model representation from `django-model` representation.

Apologizing for poor english. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are big differences between the three technologies (Graph vs Relational vs Document), an automatic conversation would probably be able to utilize only the common features of all engines.  Try keeping the same names in all models (model and field names) to be able to easily work with all technologies.  This should be easy when adding a few fields.  If you have a lot of existing models, try generating some code using [`AppConfig.get_models()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models) and [Model `_meta` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/)

Comment: Can you share some code, as a proof of concept of your idea ?

Comment: Just try looping over the results of the API methods and use `print()`